# Open and connected set

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Show that $D:=\{{(x,y)\in R^2 : y>1,x<4,y<\sqrt{x}}\}$ is an open set.
Show that D is a connected set.
my attempt was to  use interior points but since is in $R^2$ I get confused. thanks for your help

Comment: The aim is to prove part of Green's theorem, inequalities should be strict in this case since a curve C is the border of D. Sorry for the confusion, anyway, to show is connected gets me also confused.

Comment: Then edit the question to reflect this. And if $x < 0$, $\sqrt{x}$ is not defined, so is $(-1,3)$ in the set or not? The formulas do not allow to test this.

Comment: $D$ is convex and therefore  path-connected.

Answer (score 0):

It happens that your set *isn't* open. For instance, $(1,2)\in D$, but no point of the form $\left(1,2-\frac1n\right)$ (with $n\in\mathbb N$) is an element of $D$.

Comment: Sorry, didn't post the question complete, thanks for your help though

Comment: This doesn't change the fact that $D$ is not open.

Answer (score 0):

If you sketch the set you'll be able to show by inspection if it is path connected and thus connected. Regarding closure, a quick glance at the inequalities would indicate that it isn't open.

Comment: I know, sorry, didn't post the whole question since I only got stuck in one part. Thanks for y our help